# Working with service account google calendar api android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to retrieve the other accounts calendar events. For that I created a service account. But where to keep the p12 file in android studio and how to access it.

Comment: have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about this in [Creating a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount):

> Take note of the service account's email address and store the service
>   account's P12 private key file in a location accessible to your
>   application. Your application needs them to make authorized API calls.

So, it's up to you to place it inside your project folder. But then you will have to specify the path later on. A demo of using p12 in code.

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("MyProject.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN))
    .setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
    .build();
```